# Xamarin SharedProject and NetworkServices

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on cross-platform application. I have a shared project where I call some API Rest with HttpClient class. 
Now I want to add some service to detect if network is available and distinguish between Wi-Fi or a mobile network.
The following piece of code has problem because the GetSystemService cannot be found:

```
public static bool IsNetworkAvailable()
        {
#if __ANDROID__
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =  (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            return (activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected;
#elif
            return false;
#endif
```

I suppose that GetSystemService have to be call within a Context, but if I pass the context to the method it is not valid for iOS, I'm right?
I guess that this type of function cannot be set in a shared project?

Thank you!

Comment: You can get the current context from the static property : `Android.App.Application.Context`

Comment: Thank you! So this is the correct way to implement shared service?

Comment: Correct way... well *I use* it that way all the time... you could use dep. injection and reflection into your `Xamarin.Android` assembly to get it, but why incur the coding and execution overhead of that when Xamarin gives it to you via a static prop. Remember, your shared code is being compiled into the `Xamarin.Android`-based assembly. Same thing when using a Form's dependency service and they provide it to you via `Forms.Context` : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/#Android_Implementation

Comment: Ok :-) Very useful, thx

Comment: Use Xamarin.Plugin.Connectivity => https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin